# Looping through an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object, `manageEmpForm` that contains many `manageEmployee` arrays.
I need to compare 2 different instances of this object and ensure every `manageEmployee` is equal. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to construct a loop to achieve the following functionality, without the specific index numbering:

```
const initialFormValues1 = this.manageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.value[0];
const initialFormValues2 = this.manageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.value[1];
...

const currentFormValues1 = this.manageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.value[0]; 
const currentFormValues2 = this.manageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.value[1]; 
...


formHasChanged = Object.keys(this.initialFormValues1).some(key => currentFormValues1[key] != this.initialFormValues1[key]) ||
      Object.keys(this.initialFormValues2).some(key => currentFormValues2[key] != this.initialFormValues2[key])
```

Comment: Assuming you have an equal number of keys then you could use every() instead of some().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const formHasChanged = currentManageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.values.some((v, i) =>
  v != initialManageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.values[i]
)
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
const formHasChanged = !currentManageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.values.every((v, i) =>
  v === initialManageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.values[i]
)
```

Note that both `.some()` and `.every()` accept a callback function with arguments: `(element, index, array)`.

**Working Example**

```js
const initialManageEmpForm = {
  controls: {
    manageEmployees: {
      values: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  }
}
const currentManageEmpForm = {
  controls: {
    manageEmployees: {
      values: [1, 2, 4]
    }
  }
}


const formHasChanged1 = currentManageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.values.some((v, i) =>
  v != initialManageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.values[i]
)

const formHasChanged2 = !currentManageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.values.every((v, i) =>
  v === initialManageEmpForm.controls.manageEmployees.values[i]
)


console.log(formHasChanged1);
console.log(formHasChanged2);
```